# Running multi-module programs in NASM assembly language

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, nasm, multi-module

I am trying to run *main4.asm* with a subprogram found in a different module *sub4.asm*.

However when I compile *main4.asm* by:

```
nasm -f win32 main4.asm,
gcc -o main4 main4.obj driver.c asm_io.obj
```

I always get the error:

> main4.obj:main4.asm:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to 'get_int'
> main4.obj:main4.asm:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to 'print_sum'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

How can I fix this error?

These are my codes:

**main4.asm**

```
 %include "asm_io.inc"

 segment .data

          sum dd 0

 segment .bss

          input resd 1

 segment .text

          global  _asm_main

          extern  get_int, print_sum

 _asm_main:
          enter 0,0 ; setup routine
          pusha
          mov edx, 1 ; edx is ’i’ in pseudo-code
 while_loop:
          push edx ; save i on stack
          push dword input ; push address on input on stack
          call get_int
          add esp, 8 ; remove i and &input from stack
          mov eax, [input]
          cmp eax, 0
          je end_while
          add [sum], eax ; sum += input
          inc edx
          jmp short while_loop
 end_while:
          push dword [sum] ; push value of sum onto stack
          call print_sum
          pop ecx ; remove [sum] from stack
          popa
          leave
          ret
```

**sub4.asm**

```
 %include "asm_io.inc"

 segment .data

         prompt db ") Enter an integer number (0 to quit): ", 0

 segment .text

         global get_int, print_sum

 get_int:
         enter 0,0
         mov eax, [ebp + 12]
         call print_int
         mov eax, prompt
         call print_string
         call read_int
         mov ebx, [ebp + 8]
         mov [ebx], eax ; store input into memory
         leave
         ret ; jump back to caller

 segment .data

         result db "The sum is ", 0

 segment .text

 print_sum:
         enter 0,0
         mov eax, result
         call print_string
         mov eax, [ebp+8]
         call print_int
         call print_nl
         leave
         ret
```

Comment: Your `gcc` (linker) command needs to include `sub4.obj`

Comment: Like this sir? "gcc -o main4  main4.obj sub4.obj driver.c asm_io.obj"

Comment: My bad ma'am/sir